# Output Design Time Errors in Visual Studio Error List?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, compiler-errors

I have extended the entity framework designer to include my own custom properties. However, when a user adds input in these properties, I would like to validate if the property value is correct in terms of it format, for example, I have a custom entity framework designer property called 'FilterColumns' in which a user has to add a string in the following format, '|By:FirstName(string),Surname(string),Location(string)|'. I have code that will validate that this string is formatted correctly, but I would like to notify a user in design time in the normal Error List in Visual Studio, that they have for example, forgotten to add a comma or that a datatype is not valid. Is there a way to do this. Please assist?

Comment: Wrong approach, I'd say.  What if the Error List window isn't even shown?  Designers should be interactive, errors they detect should be too.